# How to make pip install requirements automatically after cloning/checking out a repository?

Tags: pip

Well, now I should do:

```
# pip install git+<my repository url>#egg=foo
# cd src/foo
# pip install -r requirements.txt
```

How can I make pip install the requirements automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you can use install_requires in setup.py:

```
setup(name = 'foo',
      ...
      install_requires = ['bar', 'blah', 'blah2'])
```

but I still wonder if there's a way to automatically put the result of

```
pip freeze
```

as install_requires in setup.py.